# how to use header in GET request in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, get-request

I have an issue in using header in GET request in react native.

```
    await fetch(Global.base_url + 'discount/category_list', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Auth": Global.user_token,
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if(data.status == 1) {
            Global.category_list = data.data;
        } else {
            Alert.alert("Warning!", 'Error');
        }

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        Alert.alert('Warning!', 'Network error.');
    });
```

I can't get response. Invalid token response. But in post man, it works well.
[image: postman screenshot]

Please advance me if anyone can solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Your syntax looks valid. Are you sure the Global.user_token is accessible and actually contains the token at that point ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. and furthermore, I have tested with real token string. But don't work.

Comment: What’s the exact error message the browser logs in the devtools console? What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. What request headers is the browser actually sending? You can use the Network pane to check that too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! your code is valid
Check the api which got from global.

**await fetch(Global.base_url + '/discount/category_list', {**

I added '/' in the url before discount.

Try this

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Global.base_url = "http://wichz.com/api/". So fetch url doesn't have issue.